# Tensorflow Incompatible shapes error while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I have been training an object detector, was able to do this successfully with 1 class, now I have added 2 classes and a few more images to the dataset, I have regenerated xml to csv and tf records by deleting old ones, pbtxt file is correct and also deleted old checkpoints inside the training directory but when I run the training job like this:

```
python legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

following this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/?completed=/creating-tfrecord-files-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/) . I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [2,1917] vs. [4,1]
 [[Node: Loss/Match/cond/mul_4 = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Loss/Match/cond/one_hot, Loss/Match/cond/Cast_2)]]
```

Comment: Have you edited object-detection.pbtxt (inside training dir) and change `num_classes: 1` to `num_classes: 2` at the beginning of configuration file?

Comment: Yes, I have added the 2nd class with id 2, I have 2 classes, id: 1 person, id: 2 my custom object.

Comment: And set num_classes: 2?

Comment: @DavidJimenez I have set num_classes: 2 in ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config, in pbtxt file, I guess we have to add item {} , right?

Comment: Anyways, I solved this by changing model to faster_rcnn_inception_v2. However with ssd_mobile_net_v1_coco and ssd_mobile_net_v2_coco I'm not able to do that.

Comment: if you are happy with my answer feel free to mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are training Mobilenet SSD following the Obstacle Detection API tutorial you could try commenting out the "ssd_random_crop" augmentation in your config file. This worked for me. Was initially pointed out by rky0930 [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5423).